# Syntax with pound and percent sign after shell parameter name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Please explain the following syntax:

```
  i##*.

  i%.*
```

I understand what it's doing, but I want to know the general pattern (why/how is it doing so).

Code where it appears:

```
#!/bin/bash

recursive_name_change()
{
    cd "$1"
    for i in *
    do
        #echo "${i##*.}"
        if [ -d "$i" ]
        then
            recursive_name_change "$i"
        elif [ "${i##*.}" = "cpp" ]
        then
             new_name=${i%.*}".c"
        mv "$i" "$new_name"
        fi
        done
        cd ../
    }

recursive_name_change .
```

Someone please also suggest, where can I find these peculiar syntax forms from?

Comment: Did you even *try* to read the bash man page and search for `##`?

Comment: No, I didn't search it in the bash manual, but I did perform google search but did not have any useful results.

Comment: Look for "parameter expansion".

Comment: @Dunatotatos (suggested edit) This is *not* exclusively Bash, see the POSIX shell specification.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oh yes, you are right. My mistake. I saw that in the bash man, and automatically thought it was for bash only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`:

> ```
>    ${parameter#word}
>    ${parameter##word}
> ```
>
> Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just
>                 as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of
>                 parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of  parameter
>                 with  the  shortest  matching  pattern (the `#` case) or the longest matching        pattern (the `##` case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal
>                 operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is
>                 the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *,
>                 the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn,
>                 and the expansion is the resultant list.
>
> ```
>   ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
> ```
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just
>                 as  in  pathname  expansion.   If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the
>                 expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is  the  expanded
>                 value  of  parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the
>                 longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted.  If parameter is  @  or  *,
>                 the  pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn,
>                 and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter  is  an  array  variable
>                 subscripted  with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each mem-
>                 ber of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

In short, `#` removes the pattern from the left, `%` from the right, doubling the symbol makes the matching greedy. (Mnemonic: `#` is to the left of `%` on most keyboards).

Comment: `s/most keyboards/english keyboards/g`

Comment: @ceving, not just English keyboards, also keyboards found in Latin America and Spain. Google image search indicates also keyboards in India and China, so "most keyboards" is probably accurate.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Czech keyboard and the trick applies.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the section "Substring removal" in [this manual](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

> ```
> ${string##substring}
> ```
>
> Deletes longest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`.
>
> ```
> ${string%substring}
> ```
>
> Deletes shortest match of `$substring` from back of `$string`.

Comment: The ABS is generally *not* a good resource. It ignores many caveats. Ignores best practices. Includes poor quality code. etc.

Comment: Yes, but does so by using `echo ${unquoted_variable}` which is a poor practice to show.